# The Pythonic way to do this? (multiply certain elements in string)

Tags: python

I just want to calculate the product of certain elements (whose index value + 1 is in **N**) of a string.

This works fine:

```
start = 1
end = 1000000
N = (1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000) 
product = 1

concatenated_numbers_str = ''.join([str(x) for x in range(1, end + 1)])

for n in N:
    product *= int(concatenated_numbers_str[n - 1])
print(product)
```

But what is a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948291/python-product-in-built-function

Comment: @Pavel Could you please elaborate how you are going to use the `reduce()` to do the product? The numbers to be multiplied together are not available together in a separate list. How would you extract the required integers from `concatenated_numbers_str` list and multiply them together using `reduce()`?

Comment: `[int(concatenated_numbers_str[n]) for n in N]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Pavel's answer, but it should be n-1 instead of n:

```
import operator
end = 1000000
N = (1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)
concatenated_numbers_str = ''.join([str(x) for x in range(1, end + 1)])
print reduce(operator.mul, [int(concatenated_numbers_str[n-1]) for n in N], 1)
```