# python3 sum in stings each letter value

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, python-3.x

i need sum in string letters value ex.
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

v1

string = "abcd"

# #result = sum(string) so 
if string[0] and string[1] and string[2] and string[3] in alphabet:
   if string[0] is alphabet[0] and string[1] is alphabet[1] and string[2] is alphabet[2] and string[3] is alphabet[3]:
      print(a+b+c+d)

v2

string = ("ab","aa","dc",)

if string[0][0] and string[0][1] and string[1][0] and string[1][1] and string[2][0] and string[2][1] in alphabet:
   if string[0] is alphabet[0] and string[1] is alphabet[1] and string[2] is alphabet[2] and string[3] is alphabet[3]:
      print(a+b+c+d)
```

what is the solution? can you help me

Comment: Your boolean logic is entirely off-base, see [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions); a dictionary built from [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) can serve as a means to getting an integer value per letter:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

letter_value = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1)}
wordsum = sum(letter_value.get(c, 0) for c in word if c)
```

The `enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1)` produces `(index, letter)` pairs when iterated over, starting at 1. That gives you `(1, 'a')`, `(2, 'b')`, etc. That can be converted to `c: i` letter pairs in a dictionary, mapping letter to integer number.

Next, using the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) lets you pick a default value; for any character in the input string, you get to look up the numeric value and map it to an integer, but if the character is not a lowercase letter, `0` is returned instead. The `sum(...)` part with the loop then simply adds those values up.

If you need to support sequences with words, just use `sum()` again. Put the above `sum()` call in a function, and apply that function to each word in a sequence:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

letter_value = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1)}

def sum_word(word):
    return sum(letter_value.get(c, 0) for c in word if c)

def sum_words(words):
    return sum(sum_word(word) for word in words)
```

Comment: I'd use `{chr(i+96):i for i in range(1, 27)}` instead of importing `ascii_lowercase`

Comment: @StevenSummers: that's a matter of taste; I think it is self-documenting this way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are my hero

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can i do sum string combine products, i tried
sum(letter_value.get(c,0) * letter_value.values() for c in zip(m) if c) but i get error  unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'dict_values'

Comment: @PyDroid: what did you expect to multiply with?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i need to compare string sum and produc, if sum_word != product_word continue until the condition is not checked, can you help me, how to get product_word?

Comment: @PyDroid: not without more information what `product_word` is supposed to be. Are you talking about multiplying all the scores together? So `abc` would be `1 * 2 * 3`, producing `6`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes i need it, if a+b+c+d != a * b * c * d than continued condition while the results will not be

Comment: @PyDroid: use `import operator`, then `reduce(operator.mul, (letter_value.get(c, 0) for c in word if c), 1)` to produce a word product.

Answer (score 2):

The old-fashioned way is to take advantage of the fact that lowercase letters are contiguous, so that `ord(b) - ord(a) == 1`:

```
data = "abcd"
print("Sum:", sum(ord(c)-ord("a")+1 for c in data))
```

Of course you could "optimize" it to reduce the number of computations, though it seems silly in this case:

```
ord_a = ord("a")
print("Sum:", sum(ord(c)-ord_a for c in data)+len(data))
```

Comment: thanks alex, can you help me, how to get produc string? ex. if i have sum a+b+c+d than i need comapre sum and product if a+b+c+d != a * b * c * d

Comment: I googled "python product" and [boom!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7948307/699305). Second hit in the google results shows you how to do it. (Define it as shown, then use `prod()` instead of `sum()`.)